# Can't manually fire event in Firefox

Tags: javascript, dom-events

There appears to be an inconsistency between Chrome 26.0.1410.64 and Firefox 21.0

Consider http://jsfiddle.net/ZLPkk/9/

```
<div id="settings">
    <div><input id="override-1"></div>
    <div><input id="override-2"></div>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Save" id="save" disabled="disabled">
</div>
```

with

```
var save = document.getElementById('save');
var settings = document.getElementById('settings');
var value = document.getElementById('override-1');
var value2 = document.getElementById('override-2');

settings.addEventListener('change', function () {
    save.disabled = false;
}, false);

value.addEventListener('click', function () {
    value.disabled = true;
    value2.addEventListener('click', function () {
        value.value = 'wasd';
        value.disabled = false;
        var change = new CustomEvent('change', {
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true
        });
        //setTimeout(function () {
        value.dispatchEvent(change);
        //}, 1000);
    }, false);
}, false);
```

In Chrome, clicking the first textbox then the second enables the save button (as expected). In Firefox it doesn't.

If you uncomment the lines corresponding to the setTimeout, it works fine on both - http://jsfiddle.net/ZLPkk/10/

Am I misunderstanding how events work and this is an ambiguity permitted by the spec? Or is this a bug in Firefox? Chrome? Or maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: you should really consider moving to jquery.

Comment: with jQuery you need write less code for this same features and it's it's much better for cross-browser codes.

Comment: I'm using Firefox, and your code appears to work fine to me.

Comment: jQuery works, but this 'project' is for helping me to understand the 'fundamentals' of javascript to make me better rounded. Llepwryd, that's strange - I've tested Firefox 21.0 on Win7 64bit, WinXP 32bit and Ubuntu 32bit and (in the first fiddle) clicking the first textbox then the second enables the save button in none of them. What are you using?

Comment: I had a similar issue in 2019 and realized that dispatching a CustomEvent("click") in Firefox on a submit button did not work, while dispatching a MouseEvent("click") did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
value.addEventListener('click', function () {
    value.disabled = true;
    value2.addEventListener('click', function () {
        value.value = 'wasd';
        value.disabled = false;
        var change = new CustomEvent('change', {
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true
        });
        settings.dispatchEvent(change);
    }, false);
}, false);
```

Comment: This is approximately the workaround I'm using at the moment and it just makes me question why bubbling isn't reliably happening...

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, but from what I know you have to dispatch the event always

Comment: As in, you've dispatched the event directly on the element where the listener was registered. I triggered the event on a child element so in theory it should trigger in the bubbling phase - http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: I think there may be some confusion as to the bubbles/cancelable properties. Once you triggered the event by dispatching it, that's when it will bubble or not to its ancestors. Example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/szFsA/1/ - run it once and then set bubbles to false and see the behavior.

Source: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-custom-events/

Comment: Yes, I agree, but as far as I can see the only change you've made is to dispatch the event to settings instead of value? In theory dispatching it on the value should also work because it bubbles?